Does $A^t$ has no solutions for $A^tx=b$ if given that $Ax=b$ has no solution
If $Ax=b$ has no solution for a $n\times n$ matrix then then can we say $A^tx=b$ also does not have any solution?
Here $rank(A)<n$ since the system of linear equation is inconsistent and therefore determinant is $0$. Now $rank(A)=rank(A^t)$. But then I am stuck...

If $Ax=b$ has no solutions then $b \notin {\sf range}A$; it is true that ${\sf dim};{\sf range}, A={\sf dim};{\sf range}, A^\top$. But this does not mean that $b \notin {\sf range} A^\top$. You are probably thinking that because $A$ and $A^\top$ have the same rank, they also have the same range.

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} x = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ has no solutions, but $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

No. This does not work. For an $n\times n$ matrix, $$Ax=b$$ has a solution iff $b$ is in the column space (the span of the columns) of $A$. This same fact applied to $A'$ says that $A'x=b$ will have a solution iff $b$ is in the column space of $A'$. Since the column spaces of $A,A'$ need not be equal, any $b$ in the column space of $A'$ but not the column space of $A$ will be such that $$Ax=b$$ has no solution but $$A'x=b$$ has a solution.
For example, take $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Then for any $$x=\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix},$$ $$Ax=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$A'x=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ x\end{pmatrix}.$$
So $$Ax=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$$ has a solution iff $b=0$ and $$A'x=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$$ has a solution iff $a=0$.
In particular, $$Ax=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ has no solution but $$A'x=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ has a solution.
